# Make list of strings from the start of each line in file

Tags: java, regex

If I have a properties file like the one below what would be the easiest way to make a list of strings of 'environments' ?

Given:

```
qa1.url=qa1.com
qa1.log=qa.log
qa2.url=qa2.com
qa2.log=qa.log
prod.url=production.com
prod.log=prod.log
```

I want to populate a dropdown with [qa1, qa2, prod]. Is regex the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're guaranteed that the environment is first, then the [String Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method will work:

```
String s = "qa1.url=qa1.com"
String r = s.split("\\.")[0] // should be 'qa1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, regex may be good approach. You can also use Scanner and set delimiter to be everything which starts with dot until end of line (including line separators):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter("\\..*?(\r?\n|$)");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
while (sc.hasNext()){
    set.add(sc.next());
}
```

Or in Java 8 we can use fact that Scanner implements Iterator so it has access to forEachRemining method which can make this code little cleaner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
sc.useDelimiter("\\..*?(\r?\n|$)");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
sc.forEachRemaining(set::add);
```

Or we we can convert Iterable to stream and use its `distinct` method to eliminate duplicate and collect results to list like

```
List<String> collect = StreamSupport.stream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(sc,Spliterator.ORDERED)
                , false)
        .distinct()
        .collect(toList());
```